# Mapping table and a simple view with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, view, fluent

I have mapped a simple entity, let's say an invoice using Fluent NHibernate, everything works fine... after a while it turns out that very frequently i need to process 'sent invoices' (by sent invoices we mean all entities that fulfill invoice.sent==true condition)... is there a way to easily abstract 'sent invoices' in terms of my data access layer? I dont like the idea of having aforementioned condition repeated in half of my repository methods.
I thought that using a simple filtering view would be optimal, but how could it be done?
Maybe I am doing it terribly wrong and someone would help me realize it :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'd personally use repository methods, you can do this with [NHibernate filters](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters), which exist exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Yes thanks for suggestion, I've stumbled upon NH filters and indeed it can serve this purpose well... but as you and Sosh suggested i will probably stick with repository methods.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just live with the extra methods on your repository.

Comment: Hmm yes its just you repeat same condition over and over and thats certainly not a good idea, especially if anything in it changes :)